# Descompactar .zip corrompido com python

Tags: python, arquivo-zip

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso descompactar arquivos ".zip", o código que estou usando é esse:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog as dlg
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os, sys

password = b'senha123'

destino = 'C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/teste1'

Tk().withdraw() #Torna a janeka do tk invisivel

arq = askopenfilename() #seleciona um arquivo
zf = ZipFile(arq ,'r')

zf.extractall(path=destino, pwd=password)

zf.close()
print('Extração feita...')
```

Os arquivos ".zip" contém fotos dentro dele, mas às vezes algumas fotos vem corrompidas, o que faz que acabe corrompendo o arquivo ".zip" também, porém se eu usar o 7-Zip manualmente eu consigo descompactar o zip normalmente, mas com o pyhton ele dá esse erro aqui:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Cah\Pyton\proj_zip\teste_extracao_zips.py", line 17, in <module>
    zf = ZipFile(arq ,'r')
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1267, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1334, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Até agora não consegui achar solução para isso, tentei usar a biblioteca **py7zr, shutil e pyunpack** mas não consegui nenhum resultado, poderiam me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Por desencargo de consciência, haveria a possibilidade de disponibilizar um link para um desses zips corrompidos  para testes?

Answer (score 1):

se você tem outro programa que consegue abrir o zip, o melhor a fazer é descompactar em outro lugar e recriar o zip;

O trabalho de investigar  que quebrou com o zipfile do Python ao abrir esses arquivos, e torna-lo "tolerante" - seja ao defeito, seja a mudança de compatibilidade da versão nova seria ordens de grandeza maior do que
simplesmente criar um zip que funciona.

Se você recebe os arquivos zip com defeito com frequência, o que dá pra fazer é em vez de usar a ziplib, chamar um programa externo de descompactação, como o 7zip, usando  [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) (o primo rico do `os.system`). Mas é isso. Se for um arquivo só, ou poucos arquivos quebrados, melhor só recriar os arquivos e usar a zipfile mesmo.